# Redirect to https in ASP.NET MVC 5 application loads endlessly

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, http, https, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm trying to enforce a redirect from http to https for all requests to an ASP.NET MVC 5 application. Currently I have added `[RequireHttps]` annotations to all controller actions and have added the following to `Global.asax`:

```
  protected void Application_BeginRequest()
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();

    if (!Context.Request.IsSecureConnection)
    {
        // Only insert an "s" to the "http:", and avoid replacing wrongly http: in the url parameters
        Response.Redirect(Context.Request.Url.ToString().Insert(4, "s"));
    }
}
```

This action is hit on when using https, but an http request just loads endlessly and never hits the action.I've also published to a staging server, with the same results: https works fine, but http is not redirected and just endlessly loads.

It is important to be able to redirect as clients will be accessing this application via an email that contains a http link address.

How do I correctly redirect to https?

Comment: Redirecting to https should be done from IIS or Apache

Comment: Oh dang ok, guess I'll have to talk to sys admin. Assumed I'd want to do it in app. Thanks!